# Generics: How to bind input and output types?

Tags: spring, kotlin, generics

I have a collection of exception handlers and I want to store all of them in a Map instance to handle errors, but I am struggling to make the code compile:

Here is a MCVE in a single file:

```kotlin
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

//mocks
class ErrorResponse(val dummy: String)
class MissingTokenException(s: String) : Exception(s)


fun interface ExceptionToErrorResponse<E : Exception> {
    fun handle(exceptionToHandle: E): ErrorResponse
}

class MissingTokenHandler : ExceptionToErrorResponse<MissingTokenException> {
    override fun handle(exceptionToHandle: MissingTokenException) = ErrorResponse("MTH")
}

class SimpleExceptionToErrorResponse : ExceptionToErrorResponse<Exception> {
    override fun handle(exceptionToHandle: Exception) = ErrorResponse("General")
}

fun exceptionHandlers(): Map<KClass<out Exception>, ExceptionToErrorResponse<out Exception>> =
    mapOf(
        Exception::class to SimpleExceptionToErrorResponse(),
        MissingTokenException::class to MissingTokenHandler()
        )

class ExceptionHandlerController(
    private val exceptionHandlers: Map<KClass<out Exception>,
            ExceptionToErrorResponse<out Exception>>
) {

    fun <E : Exception> buildErrorResponse(ex: E): String =
        exceptionHandlers.getOrDefault(ex::class, exceptionHandlers[Exception::class]!!)
            .handle(ex).dummy
}

fun main() {
    val handler = ExceptionHandlerController(exceptionHandlers())
    handler.buildErrorResponse(Exception("Test"))
}
```

The error says
Type mismatch: inferred type is E but Nothing was expected

¿How can I fix it? ¿Why does it expect Nothing?

I've tried to remove the `out` keyword as **@Tenfour04** suggested, but then I got another compiler error:

```kotlin
// ...


fun exceptionHandlers(): Map<KClass<out Exception>, ExceptionToErrorResponse<Exception>> =
    mapOf(
        Exception::class to SimpleExceptionToErrorResponse(),
        MissingTokenException::class to MissingTokenHandler()
        ) //Compiler error: Type mismatch

class ExceptionHandlerController(
    private val exceptionHandlers: Map<KClass<out Exception>,
            ExceptionToErrorResponse<Exception>>
) {

    fun <E : Exception> buildErrorResponse(ex: E): String =
        exceptionHandlers.getOrDefault(ex::class, exceptionHandlers[Exception::class]!!)
            .handle(ex).dummy
}

fun main() {
    val handler = ExceptionHandlerController(exceptionHandlers())
    handler.buildErrorResponse(Exception("Test"))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can't be solved with a regular map and without unsafe casts. In maps all keys and all values are of the same type. In your case the type of the value depends on the type of the key, which is not supported by maps.

Fortunately, this is a relatively simple case and we can easily ensure the type safety while using unchecked casts. All we need to do is to store the map in untyped form (`*`) and then perform a cast when we are sure we picked up a correct handler:

```kotlin
class ExceptionHandlerController(
    private val exceptionHandlers: Map<KClass<out Exception>,
            ExceptionToErrorResponse<*>>
) {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <E : Exception> buildErrorResponse(ex: E): String =
        (exceptionHandlers.getOrDefault(ex::class, exceptionHandlers[Exception::class]!!) as ExceptionToErrorResponse<E>)
            .handle(ex).dummy
```

This solution works correctly as long as the contents of the map are valid - meaning that handlers are correctly matched to keys.

If possible, I suggest to not acquire the map in the constructor, because then the type safety depends on the part of the code which constructed the map. Instead, create a function that registers handlers and checks they are correctly matched with keys. This way the logic for the type safety is entirely encapsulated inside the `ExceptionHandlerController` class:

```kotlin
class ExceptionHandlerController {
    private val exceptionHandlers = mutableMapOf<KClass<*>, ExceptionToErrorResponse<*>>()
    
    ...
    
    fun <E : Exception> registerHandler(type: KClass<E>, handler: ExceptionToErrorResponse<E>) {
        exceptionHandlers[type] = handler
    }
}

fun main() {
    val handler = ExceptionHandlerController()
    handler.registerHandler(Exception::class, SimpleExceptionToErrorResponse())
    handler.registerHandler(MissingTokenException::class, MissingTokenHandler())
}
```

Even better, we can use a `reified` type and then we don't have to pass the `KClass` manually.

Also, we need to remember classes can extend other classes. We need to decide what is the expected behavior if we don't have a handler for the specific type, but we have a handler for its supertype. Right now such handler won't be found and we will use the default one.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the tips. I did not think about potential subclasses, I need to check if that may be an issue in the future